# Exclude a project for a specific target-framework from a solution-build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution in Visual Studio, C# which I would like to build in to flavors:

1. .net6.0
2. .net6.0-windows

The solution consists of multiple projects and some of them use WinForms, so these projects must be excluded from the build for .net6.0.

**Q** How can I exclude projects from the build depending on the target-framework. I'm thinking of something like employing a condition in an xml-element like

```
Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-windows' "
```

**Update** If the ab.csproj-file does not include a target-framework for .net6.0 like

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

it should be exclude from a build with `> dotnet build --framework net6.0 ...`.

Comment: Well, I don't know how it is possible but one solution I can suggest is to create another solution for the target you want; include or exclude the projects you want.

Comment: @Eldar Right now I use a solution filter to build both flavors, but I would prefer a solution with only one solution-file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "exclude from build"? Why do you want to do that? Is it performance, or do you want to exclude binaries from the output directory, or something else?

Comment: @DrewNoakes I've added an update.